# Updating keywords cache in Silk4J

Tags: eclipse

I have installed MicroFocus [SilkTest](http://www.borland.com/Products/Software-Testing/Automated-Testing/Silk-Test) (particularly Silk4J) and I keep getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
Problem Occurred
'Updating keywords cache' has encountered a problem.
com/borland/util/AssetType
```

[image: Updating keywords cache has encountered a problem]

My version of Silk is 16.0.0.7468. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silk4J 16.0 Hotfix 1 (16.0.1.7470) solves this problem.

You can get the hotfix from [Silk Support](http://supportline.microfocus.com). Log in, click *Product Updates*, then *Search updates by product name* and choose *SilkTest*. After confirming the EULA, available downloads will be shown.